# Alternately Join 2 strings - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 strings and I need to construct the below result (could be JSON):

indexLine: "id,first,last,email\n"

dataLine: "555,John,Doe,jd@gmail.com"

Result: "id:555,first:john,....;

What would be the fastest way of joining alternately those 2 strings?

I wrote this - but it seems too straight forward:

```
function convertToObject(indexLine, dataLine) { 
    var obj = {};
    var result = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < dataLine.length; j++) {
        obj[indexLine[j]] = dataLine[j]; /// add property to object   
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj); //-> String format;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's a fast and correct way to do it. Any more performance optimizations would require giving us more information about parameters and call frequency, etc, etc.

Comment: "It seems too straight forward", hey, if your code is clear and does its job, more power to you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a data line and an index line?  Can't your API call return a JSON format instead?

Comment: Since you have working code and wonder if it could be improved maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var indexLine = "id,first,last,email";
var dataLine = "555,John,Doe,jd@gmail.com";

var indexes = indexLine.split(',');
var data = dataLine.split(',');

var result = [];

indexes.forEach(function (index, i) {
    result.push(index + ':' + data[i]);
});

console.log(result.join(',')); // Outputs: id:555,first:John,last:Doe,email:jd@gmail.com
```

Comment: Seems to be faster in Firefox, but slower in Chrome: http://jsperf.com/arays-to-key-value (some changes in your code to match the original, i.e. valid JSON string).

Answer (score 0):

If you might have more than one instance of your object to create, you could use this code.

```
var newarray = [],
    thing;

for(var y = 0; y < rows.length; y++){
    thing = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
        thing[columns[i]] = rows[y][i];
    }
    newarray.push(thing)
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256257/combining-two-arrays-to-form-a-javascript-object)