# javascript , comparison between the same element of two array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array

chapter

```
[ "Chemistry", "Maths", "Physics" ]
```

file

```
[ "./pranav/Chemistry/tesgdfgdfg.md", 
  "./pranav/Chemistry/test3.md", 
  "./pranav/Chemistry/test2.md", 
  "./pranav/Physics/test45.md", 
  "./pranav/Physics/test22.md", 
  "./pranav/Maths/test2.md" 
]
```

i want to check and print the element of file that contain element of chapter 
from above you can see that chemistry is in three element so i want to print that

Comment: I tried looping over both the string
and also tried comparison between array but the problem is I don't know how to check inside the element of array file

Comment: this is still unclear, what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I want to put the element of files to chapter for example
element that belong to chemistry(file array) should come under chemistry(chapter array)

Comment: @PranavKaushik Are you asking about how to get something like [Javascript objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)?

Comment: I want it to print like
Chemistry //from array chapter
==>>./pranav/Chemistry/tesgdfgdfg.md 
  "./pranav/Chemistry/test3.md
  "./pranav/Chemistry/test2.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `file` is your array of filenames,

```
file.filter((filename) => new RegExp("Chemistry").test(filename))
```

will get you all of the filenames that have `Chemistry` in them in an array:

```
file.filter((filename) => new RegExp("Chemistry").test(filename))

> ["./pranav/Chemistry/tesgdfgdfg.md", "./pranav/Chemistry/test3.md",
   "./pranav/Chemistry/test2.md"]
```

A similar tactic can be used to find the ones that have `Physics`, or `Math` in them.

---

If you want to expand your search to incorporate all strings from `chapter`, you can loop over those keys individually:

```
chapter.map(function(subject) { 
    return file.filter((filename) => new RegExp(subject).test(filename));
})
```

will give you a list of arrays, each of which contains the matched elements of `file` for each subject in order. Observe:

```
chapter.map(...)

> [[... all files with "Chemistry"...], [... all files with "Physics" ...]
  [... all files with "Maths"...]]
```

---

Finally, if you want to create a simple object from these so you can map each `subject` to its corresponding filenames, you can do:

```
var result = {}; // create empty object
for (subject of chapter){
    result[subject] = file.filter((filename) => new RegExp(subject).test(filename));
}

result
> {"Chemistry" : [... all files with "Chemistry" ...], ... }
```

or alternatively look at [the many ways to merge two arrays into an object together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256257/combining-two-arrays-to-form-a-javascript-object).

Comment: I want to compare two array
chemistry was just an example from array chapter

Comment: Your question is far from clear. How does this not meet your needs?

Comment: @PranavKaushik Updated based on the info you have provided. Once you have an object, iterating through its keys and values is relatively straightforward.

Comment: the last one is just printing the chemistry files

Comment: @PranavKaushik Refresh your environment and try again. I made a small typo, and have removed `subject` from that line in favour of `chapter[i]`. Now it will work. Remeber: the results of the operation are stored in `result`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the function and loop through 
the file-array to get arrays for all file-array elements.
Each array will have the name of the search-term (f. e. "Chemistry").
I would suggest to make this `lowercase`.

```js
file = ["./pranav/Chemistry/tesgdfgdfg.md",
  "./pranav/Chemistry/test3.md",
  "./pranav/Chemistry/test2.md",
  "./pranav/Physics/test45.md",
  "./pranav/Physics/test22.md",
  "./pranav/Maths/test2.md"
];

chapter = ["Chemistry", "Maths", "Physics"];

function getMatching(x) {
  this[x] = new Array();
  file.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.indexOf(x) >= 0) {
      this[x].push(e);
    }
  })
  return this[x];
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(getMatching("Chemistry")));
```

Comment: It is just printing the file array

Comment: I don't want it to be just for chemistry

Comment: Chemistry 
  ====>>>all files that contain chemistry
just like that for each and every subject in chapter and also this list is dynamic so some element will add or removed so i want it for each element in the array

Comment: @PranavKaushik now you get back an array for each search.