# Combine two arrays in Javascript to create a JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two arrays:

```
headers=['medium','source', 'name']

rows=[
['direct', 'google', 'demoAccount'],
['direct', 'google', 'demoAccount'],
['direct', 'google', 'demoAccount']
]
```

how can I combine them and create a JSON with the data to hold the following :

```
   {
 {medium:direct, 
    source:google,
    name:demoAccount},
    {medium:direct, 
    source:google,
    name:demoAccount},{medium:direct, 
    source:google,
    name:demoAccount}
}
```

Comment: share some code that you tried

Comment: Thats not hard... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your desired JSON format is incorrect. Embedded objects must have a property reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining two arrays to form a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256509/5447994)

Comment: jsonisnotjavascript.com should be a thing, but this will do: http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/JSON-is-not-Javascript-Object.html

Comment: var mainArr = [];
for(var w=0; w<rows.length; w++)
{
   var innerMain = {};
   for(var w1=0; w1<rows[w].length; w1++)
   {
      innerMain[headers[w1]] = rows[w1][w1];
   }
   mainArr.push(innerMain);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` and `array#reduce`

```js
const headers=['medium','source', 'name'];

const rows=[['direct', 'google', 'demoAccount'],['direct', 'google', 'demoAccount'],['direct', 'google', 'demoAccount']];

var result = rows.map((arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((o, n, i) => {
    o[headers[i]] = n;
    return o;
  }, Object.create(null));
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: how can i remove the comma between each json in the result

Comment: Which comma are you talking about?

Comment: {{},{},{}} the ones in between

Comment: Do you want a single object? The result is providing an array, elements are separated by comma in array.

Comment: yes, I want a single object. Sorry I must have misunderstood, i'll update the questin

Comment: But then you will have only three property in your result object, as the key name will be same for all of them and Object can't have duplicate key in them.

Comment: it's meant to be used with Amazon Athena, so its fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154296/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-noor).