# Trying to mapping two different arrays coming from an API to an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have this data here coming from a backend API.

```
usage_hours: {
  devices: ["350kVA GEN", "EKEDC", "85kVA GEN"], 
  hours: [405.946, 646.132, 0]
}
```

I want to turn it to this particular data so i can render it in my react app.

```
usage_hours: [
  {
    "device_name": "350kVA GEN",
    "hours": 405.946
  },
  {
    "device_name": "EKEDC",
    "hours": 646.132
  },
  {
    "device_name": "85Kva",
    "hours": 0
  }
]
```

Please in what way can I do this?. One solution that got me close was this:

```
usage_hours.hours.map((element)=>{
  let item = Object.fromEntries(
    data.usage_hours.devices.map((el, index) => [el, element])
  );
  newData.push(item);
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256257/combining-two-arrays-to-form-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
let usage_hours = {
  devices: ["350kVA GEN", "EKEDC", "85kVA GEN"],
  hours: [405.946, 646.132, 0]
}

let result = Object.entries(usage_hours)[0][1].map((item, index)=> ({device_name: item, hours: usage_hours.hours[index]}));
console.log('Result: ', result);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I've been trying to fix this bug for almost a week. Thanks so much

Comment: Welcome. Consider also upvoting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will be helpful for you.

```js
let usage_hours = {
  devices: ["350kVA GEN", "EKEDC", "85kVA GEN"], 
  hours: [405.946, 646.132, 0]
}
let arr = [];
for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(usage_hours)) {
  key = key === 'devices' ? 'device_name' : key;
    
  for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
  let obj = val.length <= arr.length ? arr[i] : {};  
    obj[key] = val[i];
    val.length > arr.length ? arr.push(obj): false;
  }
}

/*
usage_hours: [
  {
    "device_name": "350kVA GEN",
    "hours": 405.946
  },
  {
    "device_name": "EKEDC",
    "hours": 646.132
  },
  {
    "device_name": "85Kva",
    "hours": 0
  }
]
*/
console.log(arr);
```